# Quality of linear congruential generators for random numbers

Tags: computational-physics

I'm doing some simulations of the Langevin equation, for various external forces. Being told that C's `rand()` from `stdlib.h` can introduce bias in my results, I'm using a Mersenne Twister.

Nevertheless, I would like to know (and see) exactly what kind of errors a linear congruential generator can introduce in my simulation. These are things that I have tried:

- Generating 3D tuples of randoms to try to see hyperplanes. I can't see anything.
- Doing the FFT of a large vector of random numbers. It's almost the same for both the Mersenne Twister and `rand()`.
- Checking the equipartition principle for a particle in Brownian motion. Both integrators agree in the expected value of $\langle \text{KE}\rangle=\frac{1}{2}k_BT$ with the same number of significant digits.
- Seeing how well they bin in a number of bins that is not a power two. Both give the same qualitative results, no one being better.
- Looking at Brownian paths to see clear divergences from $\langle x\rangle = 0$. Again, no luck.
- Distribution of points in a circle. Filled, and only in the perimeter. Between all of them and between nearest neighbours (Shor's answer, below in the comments). Available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/RedPointyJackson/59ac3e4bdafa781ffec00713804fe5c6), just run it with Julia 0.5.0 after installing the needed libraries (see the gist for instructions).

I would like to emphasize that I am looking for introduced bias in the context of physical simulations. For example, I have seen how `rand()` fails miserably the dieharder tests while the Mersenne Twister doesn't, but for the moment that doesn't mean too much for me.

Do you have any physical, concrete, examples on how a bad random number generator wrecks a Montecarlo simulation?

*Note: I have seen how PRNG's like `RANDU` can be awful. I'm interested on not obvious examples, of generators that look innocent but ultimately introduce bias.*

Comment: Don't have your requested examples, but have been using drand48()/srand48() rather than rand()/srand() in my own C programs. Their respective man pages document the different prng algorithms used (see man random for rand's algorithm), and I believe drand48 is generally preferable, though my detailed understanding is vanishingly small. When I want guaranteed portable reproducibility across platforms, I coded up ran1() from Numerical Recipes in C, 2nd Edition, W.H.Press, et al, Cambridge U.P. 1992, ISBN 0-521-43108-5, page 280. Works great as far as I can tell, but haven't tested quantitatively.

Comment: Use random() or drand48()/lrand48() (I alwayse use the latter for molecular dynamics and Monte Carlo simulations and it is pretty good). Also, try to use a random seed. This should be more than enough for a simulation of the single particle Langevin equation.

Comment: We used a circumference, not  circle.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you for the correction. I have updated the answer, still no luck I'm afraid.

Comment: Please note that GLIB and GLIBC are two completely unrelated libraries. Both have their PRNGs.

Comment: @Ruslan Thank you for the correction. I will be more careful in the future.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you for the clarification. I hope having implemented it right this time. About the subroutines, I just pass the random generator function to the function that makes the test. It has no effect whatsoever on the random numbers.

Comment: Wouldn't [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I asked here because I was more interested in physicists' points of view, but I will consider posting there this question if it does not get the answers I'm looking for. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Fair enough. It's on topic here, but I suspect there just isn't the critical mass of numericsers to get you a good answer. That said, the edits make the question confusing - what are they for, what do they show, where are they going, and are they really part of what you're asking? I.e. the question would be much easier to read if the formatting made it clearer what the actual question is and what's only an informative appendix.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty You are completely right. I will try to edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: To be honest, the current version doesn't help - in fact, it just gives more prominence to the appendices, which are not really what you are asking. It's not even clear why they're there - are you just trying to show that Peter Shor's suggestion doesn't work for you? If so, then say so!

Comment: Hi RedPointyJackson - you flagged this question to be migrated to [compsci.SE], but there's currently a bounty from you on it. Since the whole idea of a bounty is that you pay reputation for increased visibility, refunding the bounty after you already got three days of visibility seems wrong. Please flag again if you still wish your question to be migrated after the bounty has run out.

Comment: This is not answer to your question, but many platforms have hardware random number generation, which you can use by reading from `/dev/random` or /dev/urandom` on Linux or MacOS. If you're concerned about performance of PRNGs, this might be a better option.

Comment: @DanielShapero random and urandom are supposed to be cryptographically secure RNG, intended for cryptographic purposes, like generating keys. The *hardware* aspect of it is that on Linux, they use environmental entropy, it's not the same as hardware-accelerated. They are really not intended for anything like Monte Carlo simulations at all.

Comment: @Kirill I didn't know that, thanks for the pointer! I thought the Linux kernel RNG uses thermal noise in your machine or some such. There's always gadgets like [these](http://onerng.info/).

Comment: @DanielShapero That's all aimed at cryptography, which has different demands and constraints, not scientific-computing-level speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One interesting reference that describes a failure of a Monte Carlo simulation of a physical system due to inadequate RNG (although they didn't use an LCG) is:

A. Ferrenberg and D. P. Landau.  Monte Carlo Simulations: Hidden Errors from "Good" Random Number Generators.  Physical Review Letters 63(23):3382-3384, 1992.

The Ising models that Ferrenberg and Landua studied are good tests of RNG's because you can compare with an exact solution (for the 2-D problem) and find errors way out in the digits.  These models should show the faults in an old fashioned 32 bit arithmetic PMMLCG without too much difficulty.

Another interesting reference is:

H. Bauke and Stephan Mertens.  Pseudo Random Coins Show More Heads Than Tails.  arXiv:cond-mat/0307138 [cond-mat.stat-mech]

Bauke and Mertens make a strong case against binary linear feedback shift register style random number generators.  Bauke and Mertens have some other papers related to this.

It can be difficult to find the Marsaglia planes in a 3D scatter plot.  You can try to rotate the plot to get a better view and sometimes they'll just pop out at you.  You can also do 3D tests of statistical uniformity- for the older 32 bit LCG's, these will fail at quite small numbers of bins.  e.g. a uniformity test with a 20x20x20 grid of bins in 3 dimensions is sufficient to detect lack of uniformity for the widely used (and previously well regarded) PMMLCG with m=2^31-1, a=7^5.

Answer (score 1):

It is 
possible to use [the TestU01
suite](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html) of PRNG tests
in order to find out *which* of those tests `rand` fails. (See [TestU01: A C Library for Empirical Testing of
Random Number Generators](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/testu01.pdf) for an overview of the test suite.) That's easier than coming up with Monte Carlo simulations of one's own. In a way, it's also a question of software composability (and software correctness): given a PRNG that appears to work okay on small, simple tests, how do you know its pathological behaviours won't be triggered by a larger program?

Here is the code:

```
#include "TestU01.h"

int main() {
  // Same as rand() on my machine
  unif01_Gen* gen = ulcg_CreateLCG(2147483647, 16807, 0, 12345);

  bbattery_SmallCrush(gen);
  bbattery_Crush(gen);

  return 0;
}
```

For the *SmallCrush* suite, there are 3 tests failing out of 15 (see
*guidelongtestu01.pdf* in TestU01 for long descriptions and all the
references; these are 15 statistics from 10 tests).

- *BirthdaySpacings*: bin $n$ $t$-dimensional vectors into $d^t$ bins,
  generating $d^t$ bin counts, $I_1,\ldots$, then the number of
  collisions among $\{I_{j+1}-I_j\}$ follows approximately a known
  distribution.
- *Collision*: generate $n$ $t$-dimensional vectors in $[0,1)^t$, bins
  them into $d^t$ equal hypercubes, and count the number of collisions.
- *MaxOft*: generate $n$ groups of $t$ values in $[0,1)$, compute the
  maximum $X$ in each group, and compare the distribution of the $n$
  maxima with the theoretical distribution $\mathbb{P}(X<x) = x^t$;
  the values are $n=2\times 10^6$, $t=6$. The comparison is done
  via a chi-square test and an Anderson-Darling test: the $\chi^2$ test fails with p-value $<10^{-300}$, while the AD test passes (this AD test fails in some of the larger similar tests in Crush).

Assuming these are all "typical" Monte Carlo simulations (though they might
not be like the problems you had in mind), the conclusion is that
`rand` fails some unknown subset of them. I don't know why it is
specifically that subset, though, so it's impossible for me to say
whether it will work on your own problem or not.

*MaxOft* seems particularly suspicious, given how straightforward the description is.

Among the tests in the *Crush* suite, `rand` fails 51 out of 140 (140 statistics in 96 tests). Some of the failed tests (like *Fourier3*) are done on bit strings, so perhaps it's possible they wouldn't be relevant to you. Another curious test that fails is *GCD*, which tests the distribution of the GCD of two random integers. (Again, I don't know why this particular test fails or whether your simulation will suffer from this.)

*P.S.*: Yet another thing to note is that `rand()` is actually slower than some PRNGs that successfully pass all the *SmallCrush*, *Crush*, *BigCrush* tests, such as *MRG32k3a* (see the L'Ecuyer & Simard paper above).